# get multiple values of checkbox

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can i get multiple checked box values in codeigniter with this code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="assign[]" value="Keyur">&nbsp;Keyur<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="assign[]" value="Ritesh">&nbsp;Ritesh<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="assign[]" value="Saurabh">&nbsp;Saurabh<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="assign[]" value="Maulik">&nbsp;Maulik<br/>
```

at the controller

```
$data1 = $this->input->post('assign[]');
```

i do that but can't get values,where i make mistake????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
$this->input->post('assign');
```

It will be an array, the same thing as `$_POST['assign']`.

Example:

```
// This assumes we know the post key is set and is an array,
// but you should definitely check first
foreach ($this->input->post('assign') as $key => $value)
{
    echo "Index {$key}'s value is {$value}.";
}
```

Unfortunately, if you need to access a specific index, you'll have to assign it to a variable first or use `$_POST` instead of `$this->input->post()`. Example:

```
$assign = $this->input->post('assign');
echo $assign[0]; // First value
echo $_POST['assign'][0]; // First value
```

**Update**: As of PHP 5.4, you can access the index right from the function call like this:

```
$this->input->post('assign')[0];
```

Not that it's recommended or better, but just so you know it's possible.

Either way, make sure the post data *and* the index is set before you try to access it (*if* you need to do so this way).

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, in your controller:

```
$data1 = $this->input->post('assign'); //this returns an array so use foreach to extract data

foreach( $data1 as $key => $value){

       echo $value.' '."</br>";

}
```

I have done this to my program and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i< count($_POST['assign']); $i++){
    echo $_POST['assign'][$i] . "<br />";
}
```